# How to add a prefix to all my routes in Play Framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

In play 1.x you had the http.path param which allowed you to set a url to add to every route

[http.param](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/configuration#http)

How can I achieve someting similar in play 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked at [play's discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/2722JpogWsY/discussion%5B1-25%5D) and they helped me achieve this initial version

I create a PrefixedRequest like this

```
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
import play.api.Play.configuration

import play.api.Play.current

class PrefixedRequest(request: RequestHeader) extends RequestHeader {

    def headers = request.headers
    def queryString = request.queryString

    // strip first part of path and uri if it matches http.path config
    def path = ("^" + prefix).r.replaceFirstIn(request.path, "/")
    def uri = ("^" + prefix).r.replaceFirstIn(request.uri, "/")

    def method = request.method
    def remoteAddress = request.remoteAddress

    lazy val prefix = {
      val config = configuration.getString("http.path").getOrElse("")
      if (config.endsWith("/")) config else config + "/"
  }
}

object PrefixedRequest {
  def apply(request: RequestHeader) = new PrefixedRequest(request)
}
```

Then I used it in Global.scala

```
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
import play.api.mvc.Handler

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
    super.onRouteRequest(PrefixedRequest(request))
  }

}
```

finnally added this to application.conf

```
http.path=/prefix/
```

It seems to work, but I couln't find out how to add that prefix to the reversed routes... can anybody gimme a hand on that part?

--

Some useful links

Check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/frCfaSR24p8/discussion%5B1-25%5D) and the [docs](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaInterceptors)

Comment: apparently, these feature won't be included before version 2.1 - https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/da6bbc4

Comment: It could be great for i18n (/fr, /en...)

Comment: I think you'd be better off extending http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/mvc/WrappedRequest.html

Answer (score 32):

In Play 2.1 you can do that with the following option in `conf/application.conf`:

```
application.context="/your/prefix"
```

From Play 2.4 this property is called `play.http.context` (taken from the comment by Gman).

Comment: This is much easier than the accepted answer (which may not have worked in play 2.0)

Comment: Just to let other people coming from google know, in play 2.4 it's changed to `play.http.context` (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24)